# Copying a program shortcut to some folder: the easy way

Tags: x11, gui

Case **scenario**:

- I have installed a **program**, say `TeamViewer`.
- Now I have a beautiful icon (**shortcut**) inside the `Programs` or `DashBoard` or `Unity` or whatever it is called now on my X-Windows flavour.
- I have created a **new folder** on my Desktop, say `MyFolder`.
- I just want to move/**copy this shortcut** to that folder.

I have reviewed a zillion methods, all of them requiring creating text/config files, stablishing permissions, searching for executable files, and even installing alternate tools.

Isn't there a **simple way to do this on X-Windows**?

The Window's method is pretty fair: *just dragging* the shortcut to the `MyFolder` copies it.

**Further notes**:

- Solutions accepted for any **X-Windows interface**: `Gnome`, `XFCe`, `KDE`... etc (I don't mind to install the full graphical interface if this will solve my problem).

Comment: The same pretty fair method work on xfce ???

Comment: Working, @ctac_ . I have installed it, and, indeed, XFCe allows shortcuts dragging. You should write it down as a possible answer. Thanks you.